# Datewise Sectioned UITableView in iOS

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, uitableview

I have `NSMutableArray` which has passenger's journey that will be shown in tableview. I shows correctly in plain tableview. But I want to show in sectioned tableview where tableview headers will show date and its rows will will show all journey on that particular date.

I am not able to figure out how to first break my `NSMuatableArray` into various array(datewise) and then show it in sectioned tableView.

I am newbie to iPhone . ***Please help.***

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have a array of Dictionary with some key to identify date.

Here I posted code for devide a Mutable Array to Datewise array.

```
NSString *lastDate = @"";
NSMutableArray *aryInnerArray = nil;
NSmutableArray *aryChatConversation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in aryTempChat) {
    if (![lastDate isEqualToString:[dict objectForKey:@"date"]]) {
        if (aryInnerArray != nil) {
            [aryChatConversation addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:lastDate, @"date", aryInnerArray, @"conversation", nil]];
            [aryInnerArray release];
        }
        lastDate = [dict objectForKey:@"date"];
        aryInnerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [aryInnerArray addObject:dict];
}
if (aryInnerArray != nil) {
    [aryChatConversation addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:lastDate, @"date", aryInnerArray, @"conversation", nil]];
    [aryInnerArray release];
}
[aryTempChat release];
```

Hope this helps :)